# SharePoint Web Service Ignores Query Section of GetListItems method

Tags: php, web-services, sharepoint, soap

I'm a newbie to SharePoint web service. I'm sending this request using PHP to my SharePoint server but the my query section is completely ignored

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetListItems>
      <ns1:listName>Customers</ns1:listName>
      <ns1:query>
        <Query>
          <Where>
            <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name="ows_EMail" />
              <Value Type="Text">aaa@ddd.com</Value>
            </Eq>
          </Where>
        </Query>
      </ns1:query>
      <ns1:rowLimit>150</ns1:rowLimit>
    </ns1:GetListItems>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried so many suggestions found on forums, but nothing worked. Could anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a **query** node (note the lowercase) which is a parent to the **Query** node.  Here's an example:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>
      <listName>OpportunitiesAdmins</listName>
      <viewName></viewName>
      <query>
        <Query>
          <Where>
            <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='AdminName' />
              <Value Type='User'>Welch, Jeff (UBC)</Value>
            </Eq>
          </Where>
        </Query>
      </query>
      <viewFields></viewFields>
      <rowLimit>0</rowLimit>
      <queryOptions>
        <QueryOptions></QueryOptions>
      </queryOptions>
    </GetListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I tried this option but still I'm having the problem. Could it be the XML tags at the top of the XML request causing the problem<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. And I have edited the question with latest code.

Comment: Try putting a xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/' attribute on the GetListItems rather than defining the namespace prefix 'ns1'.  Also, consider adding the xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' attributes to your Envelope node.